# Inner classes - Inheritance and overriding their attributes

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to understand how Django uses python's metaclasses for it's database models (options) and came up with the following stripped down code snippet that should roughly mimic Django's logic.

```
class DatabaseOptions(object):

    def __init__(self, opts):
        if opts:
            for key, val in opts.__dict__.items():
                if not key.startswith('__') and not callable(val):
                    setattr(self, key, val)


class MetaModel(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        result = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dict(classdict))

        opts = classdict.pop('DbMeta', None)
        if opts:
            setattr(result, '_db_meta', DatabaseOptions(opts))

        return result


class Model(object, metaclass=MetaModel):

    class DbMeta:
        database = 'default'
        migrate = True


class User(Model):

    class DbMeta(Model.DbMeta):
        database = 'user'


class GroupUser(User):

    class DbMeta(User.DbMeta):
        database = 'group_user'
```

Using the above code, I would expect the following output:

```
print(Model._db_meta.database)  # default
print(Model._db_meta.migrate)  # True

print(User._db_meta.database)  # user
print(User._db_meta.migrate)   # True

print(GroupUser._db_meta.database)  # group_user
print(GroupUser._db_meta.migrate)  # True
```

Instead I get the following exception

```
>>> python3 test.py 
default
True
user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 48, in <module>
    print(User._db_meta.migrate)   # True
AttributeError: 'DatabaseOptions' object has no attribute 'migrate'
```

My question would be why `User.DbMeta` does not inherit the `migrate` attribute from `Model.DbMeta`? Is there any solution for this kind of problem?

**Edit**:

According to Daniel's answer I came up with the following that worked for me:

```
class DatabaseOptions(object):

    def __init__(self, opts):
        if opts:
            for key in dir(opts):
                if not key.startswith('__'):
                    val = getattr(opts, key, None)
                    if not callable(val):
                        setattr(self, key, val)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a question about inner classes specifically.

Class attributes are just that, attributes of the class itself. So, the `__dict__` of `Model.DbMeta` contains "database" and "migrate", but the one of `User.DbMeta` contains *only* "database" because that is the only attribute defined by that class.

However, those attributes *are* shown by `dir()`; you should probably iterate over the results of calling that on the class in DatabaseOptions rather than `__dict__`.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. I have totally overseen this issue. Using `dir()` did the trick.